# Using an aggregate function that resets after condition is met?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with event data and currently trying to work out time spent within an application by summing the difference of the current and previous timestamps. The problem however, is that I need to reset this value, each time the value of a column 'packageName' changes. I have tried to use the following.

```
SELECT    
    SUM(timeDifference) OVER(PARTITION BY packageName ORDER BY sNumber, timestamp) as accTime,
    *
FROM table.name
ORDER BY
    sNumber, timestamp
```

However the result of this is seemingly too intelligent. I need it to forget it's aggregation after each partition, instead of remembering earlier results and accumulating those.

My question is whether there is any way to reset this. I will give examples of what I am getting, and of what my desired output is. Any help would be much appreciated .

What I'm getting.

```
**accTime      diff         packageName**
10              10          com.package.1
20              20          com.package.1
10              10          com.package.2
20              20          com.package.2
30              10          com.package.1
```

What I want.

```
**accTime      diff         packageName**
10              10          com.package.1
20              20          com.package.1
10              10          com.package.2
20              20          com.package.2
10              10          com.package.1
```

The second example shows that the accumulated time for "first" gets reset, which is what I need help with.

To help further explain myself, here is sample of original data:

```
**timestamp          packageName          sNumber      eventID      diff**
  1433119125117      com.package.1        xx123xx      event1       null
  1433119125200      com.package.1        xx123xx      event2         83
  1433119125400      com.package.2        xx123xx      event3        200
  1433119125600      com.package.2        xx123xx      event4        200
  1433119125800      com.package.1        xx123xx      event5        200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the lag function (you will notice my answer looks like Pentium's), I THINK this is what you want...

I'm not 100% sure, since your accTime seems to behave weirdly from your diff... to me, accTime should be accTime+diff, no? (if I'm wrong, correct me, with where the query is right now, it's easy to tweak it :) )

```
SELECT
  timestamp,package,sNumber,eventID,diff,
  CASE WHEN lagPackage IS NULL then 0
  WHEN package != lagPackage THEN diff 
  ELSE (diff + IF(lagDiff is null, 0,lagDiff)) END AS accTime
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG(package,1) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS lagPackage,
    LAG(diff,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) AS lagDiff
  FROM (
    SELECT
      1433119125117 AS timestamp,
      'com.package.1' AS package,
      'xxx123xxx' AS sNumber,
      'event1' AS eventID,
      NULL AS diff),
    (
    SELECT
      1433119125200 AS timestamp,
      'com.package.1' AS package,
      'xxx123xxx' AS sNumber,
      'event2' AS eventID,
      83 AS diff),
    (
    SELECT
      1433119125400 AS timestamp,
      'com.package.2' AS package,
      'xxx123xxx' AS sNumber,
      'event3' AS eventID,
      200 AS diff),
    (
    SELECT
      1433119125600 AS timestamp,
      'com.package.2' AS package,
      'xxx123xxx' AS sNumber,
      'event4' AS eventID,
      200 AS diff),
    (
    SELECT
      1433119125800 AS timestamp,
      'com.package.1' AS package,
      'xxx123xxx' AS sNumber,
      'event5' AS eventID,
      200 AS diff),
  ORDER BY
    timestamp )
```

From the sample set you gave, this returns :

```
Row timestamp       package         sNumber  eventID    diff    accTime  
1   1433119125117   com.package.1   xxx123xxx   event1  null    0    
2   1433119125200   com.package.1   xxx123xxx   event2  83      83   
3   1433119125400   com.package.2   xxx123xxx   event3  200     200  
4   1433119125600   com.package.2   xxx123xxx   event4  200     400  
5   1433119125800   com.package.1   xxx123xxx   event5  200     200
```

Comment: @RyanMcClarnon very welcome sir :) It was actually fun to play around with SQL to make this fit ^^. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile was playing with some sample. This is not a complete answer but maybe helps someone.

```
select 
  pos,label,diff,
  if (lag!=label or lag is null,1,0) as reset
from(
  select 
    pos,label,diff,
    LAG(label, 1) OVER (ORDER BY pos asc) lag,
  from (select 10 as diff,'first' as label, 1 as pos),
    (select 20 as diff,'first' as label, 2 as pos),
    (select 10 as diff,'second' as label, 3 as pos),
    (select 20 as diff,'second' as label, 4 as pos),
    (select 10 as diff,'first' as label, 5 as pos),
    (select 11 as diff,'first' as label, 6 as pos),
    (select 12 as diff,'first' as label, 7 as pos),
  order by pos
)
```

this returns

```
+-----+-----+--------+------+-------+---+
| Row | pos | label  | diff | reset |   |
+-----+-----+--------+------+-------+---+
|   1 |   1 | first  |   10 |     1 |   |
|   2 |   2 | first  |   20 |     0 |   |
|   3 |   3 | second |   10 |     1 |   |
|   4 |   4 | second |   20 |     0 |   |
|   5 |   5 | first  |   10 |     1 |   |
|   6 |   6 | first  |   11 |     0 |   |
|   7 |   7 | first  |   12 |     0 |   |
+-----+-----+--------+------+-------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This should help me with defining when the query should reset it's SUM operation, still need to work out exactly how to do that though.